# Pass audio spectrum to a shader as texture in libGDX

Tags: kotlin, libgdx, glsl, shader

I'm developing an audio visualizer using **libGDX**.

I want to pass the audio spectrum data (an array containing the FFT of the audio sample) to a shader I took from **Shadertoy**: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ttfGzH.

In the GLSL code I expect an uniform containing the data as texture:

`uniform sampler2D iChannel0;`

The problem is that I can't figure out how to pass an arbitrary array as a texture to a shader in libGDX.

I already searched in SO and in libGDX's forum but there isn't a satisfying answer to my problem.

Here is my Kotlin code (that obviously doesn't work xD):

```
val p = Pixmap(512, 1, Pixmap.Format.Alpha)
val t = Texture(p)
val map = p.pixels
map.putFloat(....) // fill the map with FFT data
[...]
t.bind(0)
shader.setUniformi("iChannel0", 0)
```

Comment: What if you created the `Texture` after you load data to the `Pixmap`?

Comment: @Genhis nothing bro :(

Comment: you should call shader.begin() before setting uniforms.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the `drawPixel` method and store your data in the first channel of each pixel just like in the shadertoy example (they use the red channel).

```
float[] fftData = // your data

Color tmpColor = new Color();
Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(fftData.length, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
for(int i = 0; i < fftData.length i++)
{
    tmpColor.set(fftData[i], 0, 0, 0); // using only 1 channel per pixel
    pixmap.drawPixel(i, 0, Color.rgba8888(tmpColor));
}
// then create your texture and bind it to the shader
```

To be more efficient and require 4x less memory (and possibly less samples depending on the shader), you could use 4 channels per pixels by splitting your data accross the r, g, b and a channels. However, this will complexify the shader a bit.

This data being passed in the shader example you provided is not arbitrary though, it has pretty limited precision and ranges between 0 and 1. If you want to increase precision you may want to store the floating point accross multiple channels (although the IEEE recomposition in the shader may be painful) or passing an integer to be scaled down (fixed point). If you need data between -inf and inf you may use sigmoid and anti sigmoig functions, at the cost of highly reducing the precision again. I believe this technique will work for your example though, as they seem to only require values between 0 and 1 and precision is not super important because the result is smoothed.

Comment: Since this is a real-time updated FFT, I would think you'd only want to create the Texture and Pixmap once and use `texture.draw(pixmap, 0, 0)` to apply the pixmap changes each time the data is updated.